# Create an 'undo' function in a drawing app in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am attempting to create a drawing app in Swift 2, and have hit a wall whilst trying to implement an 'undo' button. I am quite new to this (very new actually), and have tried my best to figure it out, but all of the other examples of this that I have found are either in different versions or languages, or just don't apply... Perhaps it is my lack of knowledge that is inhibiting my progress here.

I have tried using the 'undoManager,' but I don't know how to use it. I have tried reading the available online guides and am still clueless!

Here is my button:

```
@IBAction func undoDrawing(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

I have set up `touchesBegan`:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
        isSwiping    = false
    if let touch = touches.first{
        lastPoint = touch.locationInView(imageView)
    }
}
```

`touchesMoved`:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    isSwiping = true;
    if let touch = touches.first{

        let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(imageView)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
        self.imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height))
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGLineCap.Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myCGFloat)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.selectedColor.CGColor)
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}
```

and `touchesEnded`:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           withEvent event: UIEvent?){

    if(!isSwiping) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
        self.imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height))
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGLineCap.Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myCGFloat)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.selectedColor.CGColor)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

So all I need is a method by which to reverse the actions undertaken by these 'touches.' Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid that you'll have to comment your code and be more specific

Comment: look at using NSUndoManager

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have tried to edit it down so that is it clearer... I would love to use NSUndoManager... that sounds ideal. My issue I suppose is 'what am I undoing?' How do I store the information given by these methods and then access it to reverse / undo it from the 'undo' button?

Comment: Append the lines to an array for every swipe. Then when the 'undo' button is pressed remove the last object of the array from the view and the array.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two ways to go about this, the easy & limited way and the hard & generalized way.

---

### Easy Way

The simplest way, which will only allow the undoing of a single change, is to maintain a second copy of the image in memory. In pseudocode,

```
// Update contents of backupImage, draw new line on currentImage
drawNewLine {
    backupImage = currentImage 
    drawLineOnCurrentImage()
}

// Revert currentImage to most-recent backupImage
undo {
    currentImage = backupImage
}
```

This is similar to the scheme [used by the original MacPaint](http://basalgangster.macgui.com/RetroMacComputing/The_Long_View/Entries/2010/7/31_MacPaint.html) (see "Question #3:  How do you do undo?").

This method does not allow for Redo, nor does it require (or allow) use of `NSUndoManager`.

---

### Hard Way

For a more general solution, you need to figure out how to represent each drawing event as a *reversible* function.

**Primitive example app**

Imagine that the only operation your drawing app supports is scaling. Thus,

```
scale(image, 2.0)   // push 2.0 onto stack - current size = 2.0x
scale(image, 3.0)   // push 3.0 onto stack - current size = 6.0x
```

returns an image that's six times the size. You could represent this operation with a stack of floats, like `scaleHistory = [2.0, 3.0]`.

Then, your undo function would be

```
undo(image) {
    scale(image, 1 / scaleHistory.lastObject())
    scaleHistory.removeLastObject()
}
```

Continuing the execution from above,

```
undo(image) // Pop 3.0 from the stack. Scale by 1 / 3.0, new size = 2.0x
undo(image) // Pop 2.0 from the stack. Scale by 1 / 2.0, new size = 1.0x
```

Now that `scaleHistory` is empty, you should disable the `undo` button!

This is the paradigm expected by `NSUndoManager`; see [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/UndoManager.html), which describes the use of the undo stack.

**How to make this work in your app**

One way I see for you to implement this paradigm is to replace drawing directly on the image with recording the intention of the drawing action in a data structure. Thus, you would have a vector of `CGPoint` pairs representing the lines added by the user. In pseudocode,

```
lines = []

addLine(start, finish) {
    lines.addObject((start, finish))
    draw()
}

draw() {
    canvas = nil
    foreach (lines as line) {
        canvas.paintToScreen(line)  // this function invokes CGContextMoveToPoint, CGContextAddLineToPoint, etc.
    }
}

undo() {
    lines.removeLastObject()
    draw()
}

canUndo() {
    return lines.count > 0
}
```

Crucially, you must reset your `canvas` upon each invocation of `draw()` so that you can be sure each line in `lines` is rendered exactly once.

Of course, this isn't an exact analog to the scaling app, because `undo()` doesn't simply apply the inverse of the last operation. Rather, we reset the image on screen - *equivalent to undoing all the operations* - and then *selectively re-do the ones we want to keep* in the `draw()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will have a go at these ideas and see if i can work it out... I will be back with updates soon.

Comment: Thanks again for your input on this subject. I have had a go at implementing the ideas you have suggested, but I simply don't know where to position them in my code, and what prefixes to use (like func, var etc...). I am very new to this and it is like a foreign language to me so please forgive my lack of understanding! I have read the info on stacks and undoManager, and still feel like this is beyond me. I am going to continue with the course that I am learning from and come back to this at a later date when I have a bit more knowledge under my belt. Kind regards

Comment: Kudos for taking on the challenge. The app you're trying to create requires a healthy dose of abstract thinking, which you'll no doubt grow into as you gain experience.